# Why does apt-get purge cause new packages to be installed?

Tags: apt, package-management

after entering `sudo apt-get purge cheese-common` in the terminal, the ouput included the following:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apparmor-easyprof apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu click click-apparmor
  gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 libclick-0.4-0 python3-apparmor
  python3-apparmor-click python3-click-package python3-libarmor
```

Why is it that removing a package causes new packages to be installed?  And how are any of these related to cheese-common? fyi, This message does not occur when I remove other packages.

Comment: possibly satisfying dependencies caused by removing cheese-common. or you had broken package that it is automatically fixing.

Comment: Could you explain how removing a package could add dependencies?

Comment: a package could have a dependency satifisfied by 2 packages. thus removing one would make apt satisfy the dependency with the other

Comment: I think maybe cheese-common fulfilled some dependencies for other packages. Purgin it might cause those packages to auto fulfill their dependecies with the dependecies originally planed for them..?

Comment: @derHugo ah, ok, I can see how that makes sense